# Error inflating class com.iammert.library.readablebottombar.ReadableBottomBar

Tags: android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I'm using ReadableBottomBar library in my project
and I have created XML folder for tabs and I have inflated bottom bar in my layout as you see in pictures:

[image]

[image]

but unfortunately I get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bhJ3.png)

how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the hardcoded strings in tabs.xml to string resources fixed my problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPxxJ.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).